# Entity Framework 6.1.1 Searching for NULL Guid does not work

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is this a bug in Entity Framework 6.1.1 ?

When I run the following Linq query I don't get any results.

```
var emptyGroups = context.ActiveDirectoryUsersGroupsStagings
                .Where( x => x.GroupId == null).ToList( );
```

However, running the following SQL query.  I do get results (7 records).

```
select * from ActiveDirectoryUsersGroupsStagings
where GroupId is null
```

Here's the table structure ...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActiveDirectoryUsersGroupsStagings](
[UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[GroupId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[distinguishedName] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ActiveDirectoryUsersGroupsStagings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)
```

Comment: Have you tried GUID.Empty ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the case but have you tried modifying your linq query to compare the GroupId property to Guid.Empty?

```
 var emptyGroups = context.ActiveDirectoryUsersGroupsStagings
            .Where( x => !x.GroupId.HasValue).ToList( );
```

Comment: Does the GroupId column actually contain NULL as the value in the database?

Comment: select * from ActiveDirectoryUsersGroupsStagings
where GroupId is null

Comment: Is your GroupId property on your Entity defined as Nullable?  If so you may want to change your query expression.  I have updated my answer above to reflect a nullable property check.

Comment: That did the trick!  My model didn't reflect a nullable Guid (Guid?).  Thanks everyone